# How to match SPSS Files but also keep the extra, original data from one of the files?

Tags: merge, match, spss

File 1 has 300k rows
File 2 has 200k rows

I want to match the two files, so I've been using the following function.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE File 1
SORT CASES BY ID
DATASET ACTIVATE File 2
SORT CASES BY ID

MATCH Files /FILE= File 1*
/TABLE ='File 2'
/RENAME ....
/BY ID
/DROP ....
EXECUTE
```

On top of matching the cases that share the same ID, I want to keep the original unmatched data from File 1 in my resulting file.

I tried adding the resulting matched files back to File 1, but I realized that method would duplicate many of the cases.

Comment: Something I don't understand - when `file=file1/table=file2` by definition what you get is all the cases from file1 and only matching cases from file2. So maybe you mean you want to keep unmatched cases from file2? If so, try this: `file=file1/file=file2`.